# Firestore not import Blob but string values

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-firestore

I Want to import data from csv file to Firestore. I have this csv :

```
Name, First name
alice, tutu
..., ...
```

I have this script but my data are importing to firebase as "blob". I want import the item as string...

How i can import data in string ?

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
store = firestore.client()
file_path = "travail2.csv"
collection_name = "Etablissements"

def batch_data(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
       yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]

data = []
headers = []
with open(file_path) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            for header in row:
                headers.append(header)
            line_count += 1
        else:
            obj = {}
            for idx, item in enumerate(row):
                obj[headers[idx]] = item
            data.append(obj)
            line_count += 1

for batched_data in batch_data(data, 499):
    batch = store.batch()
    for data_item in batched_data:
        doc_ref = store.collection(collection_name).document()
        batch.set(doc_ref, data_item)
    batch.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the way strings are interpreted by Firestore client libraries depending if you're using Python 3 or 2. I have been able to reproduce your issue in both versions and my results have been the following:

When working with Python3.7 documents are created with string datatype right away. When working with Python2.7 documents are created with the Blob Datatype unless you explicitly convert every string to Unicode datatype either with `unicode(var)` or `u'{}'.format(var)`.

I think this comes from the differences on how 2.7 and 3 versions treat strings internally. As said in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Blob) the Blob datatype represents an array of bytes which is not exactly the same as a string which needs to be utf-8 encoded. You might also take a look at [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1847#issuecomment-224946671) Github issue about Cloud Datastore which seems to point in this line of thought even though it's from another product.

So from my perspective your options to actually get the desired string type would be to use Python3 or to change your data encoding format by the substitution of `obj[headers[idx]] = item` with `obj[headers[idx]] = unicode(item)`. I will prefer the first since support for Python2 is being dropped next January.

Answer (score 0):

Blob indiates Binary Large Object. its a text column

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Blob

Comment: you can explain please ?